# How can I make my code run faster?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm currently working on a piece of code which blurs an image by taking a circular sample of pixels around each pixel, finding their mean and then applying that to the central pixel. It works, but it takes ages, especially with large images and large radii.

Can anyone give me some tips on how to speed this up?

```
function [] = immean(IMAGE, r)

%Find the maximum width, nx, and maximum height, ny, of the image - so that
%it can be used to end the for-loop at the appropriate positions.

[nx, ny] = size(IMAGE);

%Create a completely black image of the same size as the subject image,
%into which the appropriate pixel values can be fed.

average = uint8(zeros(size(IMAGE)));

%Loop through all the pixels of the image.

for x = 1:nx
  for y = 1:ny

     %This next code takes a square sample of pixels, with dimensions of 
     %r x r.
     %First, set the boundaries of this square, from which the circular
     %sample of pixels will be taken.

     if x-r <= 0
         startx = 1;
     else
         startx = x-r;
     end

     if x+r > nx
         endx = nx;
     else
         endx = x+r;
     end

     if y-r <= 0
         starty = 1;
     else
         starty = y-r;
     end

     if y+r > ny
         endy = ny;
     else
         endy = y+r;
     end

     %Loop through this square sample and, if the pixel is within the
     %range of the circle, add its intensity to the total.

     total = 0;
     pixelcount = 0;

     for xp = startx : endx

       for yp = starty : endy  

             if (x-xp)^2 + (y-yp)^2 <= r^2
               total = total + uint32(IMAGE(xp, yp));
               pixelcount = pixelcount + 1;
             end
       end
     end

     mean = total / pixelcount;
     average(x,y) = mean;

   end
end

imshow(average)
```

I've tried changing things like `uint32` but that hasn't worked. Beyond that, I'm a bit of a beginner, so I'm not sure what the best tricks are in this situation. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I guess you could calculate `r^2` outside all loops. And move `(x-xp)^2` outside the innermost loop to the next higher loop.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Nice suggestion. There's nothing I'm getting fundamentally wrong then? Big images (660x400) are taking about 30 minutes to process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loops are extremely slow in MATLAB.  As a rule, you should always vectorize your code where possible.  This is one of those cases.  Looping through every pixel is painfully slow.

MATLAB has a function **imfilter** which does basically what you want.  Since you are just taking the average intensity, a simple filter function will do this quite well and very fast.  You can define the filter coefficients as a matrix:

```
% Define a 2D Filter with radius r:
d = 2*r+1;
h = zeros(d);

% Now make it a "circular" filter (keeping it square would be much easier 
% and probably look the same but whatever):
[x, y] = meshgrid(1:d,1:d);
distance = sqrt((x-(r+1)).^2 + (y-(r+1)).^2);
h(distance<=r) = 1;
h = h / sum(h(:))

% Now pump it into imfilter and youre done:
average = imfilter(uint32(IMAGE), h);
```

Also, there are a TON of MATLAB image processing tools, so search around a bit and you'll probably find helpful tools for whatever your working on, no need to reinvent the wheel.  I don't have an image in front of me to test this one but let me know if it works.

Comment: It depends on what you're doing inside the `for` loop, but in certain cases, due to JIT acceleration, the `for` loop can perform just as well as any vectorized solution if you use more recent versions of MATLAB.  However, for this **particular** case, it will certainly be slow and vectorized is preferred.